# Calculate equation of y(n) using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I have been trying to calculate equation of y(n) from the difference equation of the form

> y(n) = a1*x(n) + a2*x(n-2) + a3*y(n-1) + a4*y(n-2)

where x(n) = [0,2,3,5,1] using MATLAB.

Till now this has been my approach :

```
a = [a1,0,a2];
b = [1,-a3,-a4];
c = [0,2,3,5,1];
n1 = 0:length(a)-1;
n2 = 0:length(b)-1;
n3 = 0:length(c)-1;
w = 0:pi/12:2*pi;
num = a*exp(-1j*n1'*w);
den = b*exp(-1j*n2'*w);
H = num ./ den;
X = c*exp(-1j*n3'*w);
Y = X .* H;
disp(Y);
```

But I am getting the output as follows :

```
  Columns 1 through 4

   6.0000 + 0.0000i   0.7191 - 5.8288i  -4.8429 - 0.1127i   0.1649 + 2.1811i

  Columns 5 through 8

   0.7374 + 0.2036i   0.2017 - 0.1831i  -0.0119 - 0.0962i  -0.0302 - 0.0144i

  Columns 9 through 12

  -0.0090 + 0.0071i   0.0010 + 0.0039i   0.0011 + 0.0003i   0.0001 - 0.0001i

  Columns 13 through 16

   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0001 + 0.0001i   0.0011 - 0.0003i   0.0010 - 0.0039i

  Columns 17 through 20

  -0.0090 - 0.0071i  -0.0302 + 0.0144i  -0.0119 + 0.0962i   0.2017 + 0.1831i

  Columns 21 through 24

   0.7374 - 0.2036i   0.1649 - 2.1811i  -4.8429 + 0.1127i   0.7191 + 5.8288i

  Column 25

   6.0000 + 0.0000i
```

Please bear with me. I am new to MATLAB. Thanks !

Comment: if you want to use the fft approach, then you need to do ifft at the end. also the way you do fft does not seem right

Comment: Your system is second degree but you have a fifth order initial condition. I think there is a mismatch somewhere